# CakePhp Plugin: Problems with routing

Tags: cakephp

Well, I am struggling for 2 hours trying to finding out how this not works.
The problem:
I have a plugin PaypalIpn in the Plugin Folder. The Plugin has a controller InstantPaymentNotificationsController and some actions inside.

If I try to access directly the plugin's controller with /paypal_ipn/instant_payment_notifications Cake says the there is no Paypal Controller.
Well, I added a route:

```
Router::connect('/paypal_ipn/:action/*', array( 'plugin' => 'paypal_ipn', 'controller' => 'instant_payment_notifications', 'action' => 'index'));
```

and surprise the webserver freezes and this errors is fired in httpd.log

```
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of -2147483648 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 320596 bytes) in libCake2.3/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php on line 114
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [plugin's installation notes](https://github.com/webtechnick/CakePHP-Paypal-IPN-Plugin) the route should be:

```
Router::connect('/paypal_ipn/process',
    array('plugin'     => 'paypal_ipn',
          'controller' => 'instant_payment_notifications',
          'action'     => 'process'
    )
);
```

This is not what you have.

Also, be sure you have the latest version. The article on Bakery is from 2009 and is about a very old version.

Comment: It does not matter.I modified that plugin for Cake 2.0. I use only the helper. The fact is that I am not able to access the plugin's controller methods, like index.

Comment: For sure. But the problem is that the server "freezes", like falling into an infinite loop which exhausts the memory.

Comment: Yes. It sounds like infinite redirects, which means something is wrong with `routes.php`. Does it work fine if you remove PayPalIPN's route?

Comment: Well, if I remove the PayPal IPN I can't access anymore the controller's action and Cake complains with a "missing controller/action" error. I don't know (now) what is causing this problem...